# NSURL fileURLWithPath:isDirectory: doesn't work properly

Tags: nsurl

What I wanna do is just accessing to local file system from my iPhone.
I have some files in Library directory.

So, my code is as below.

```
NSString *dir = @"/Users/MY_ID/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/6AB76439-APP-ID-1C1BB92E/Library/test";
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dir isDirectory:NO];
```

Then, what I got for the value of url is,

```
file://localhost/Users/MY_ID/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/6AB76439-APP-ID-1C1BB92E/Library/test
```

and both iPhone simulator and a real iPhone CANNOT resolve this url.

I think the problem is this part.

```
file://localhost
```

because, without that part, I can read file from string.

But, what I need to do is to get the "test" file via NSURL.

Since [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:] method only can read NSURL.

let me read the video file from my local file system.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is clearly not useful outside of your local test environment (and hence not portable code anyway), why not just create a "localhost" symlink in the root of your machine?

```
ln -s / /localhost
```

I wasn't even aware the MPMoviePlayerViewController could read a file from the local filesystem in this way. For simplicity, why not bundle your movie file into the app or host it on something like dropbox?

Comment: i can't, since i'm dynamically making this test file by getting data from the web.

Comment: You can't what? Use the symlink, or host the test files remotely? Assuming the symlink doesn't work: set up Apache and use your IP address, e.g. "http ://192.168.0.2/testfile.mpg". This will be a better test, since you will need to do something similar with the production build. I'd be surprised if the iPhone device/emulator manages to read from your local filesystem at all.